# How many hours a day should we dedicate to spending time with our children vs. learning?

Tags: torah-study, children-parenting, chinuch-education

As far as I can tell from experience, common wisdom, common sense and perhaps my Torah learning, it seems quality time spent talking, playing and generally interacting with one's parents is like oxygen for a child.

This makes me wonder, does the Torah place any form of obligation on parents to spend time with their children beyond the simply "veshinantam levanecha"? A schedule of any sort? X hours per day per child?

I understand I am not articulating this question well so please help me refine it. It is important. Shavua tov.

Comment: In Hayom Yom, the Rebbe writes: "so too is it an absolute duty for every person to spend a half hour every day thinking about the Torah-education of children" (Teves 22). Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Shmuel no but wow thanks incredible. How much time actually spent interacting with children? Age by age

Comment: I am not a father, but I have a feeling that this is not written down exactly like you write. I do not think there are sources that stress that we need to spent, let's say, 1,5 hours for child a, b, c. etc.... Don't you think? - I do think that there are sources that stress the need to spend time with children though, although not 1,5 hours etc...

Comment: @Shmuel well, I have no idea. There are a lot of commentaries and the Rebbe would do things like that... age 2 learn cleanliness, age 3 learn music etc. But even still, anything towards this would be useful, even the most subtle off hand comment!

Comment: You might want to have a look here: https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/letters/default_cdo/aid/992310/jewish/Education.htm

Comment: @RabbiKaii https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gESWSr-8d1Y Rabbi Keleman discusses how prayer was not set for one's kid, despite indeed one should always pray for them since kids are extremely unique what will work for one may not work for another. Chazal would not give a time as each kid and parent's situation is different. some children need constant attention some less...

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy I will watch it thanks. Does that imply that one is allowed to forgo all learning while one's child is home and awake and spend all of it with him, if the child needs it?

Comment: in the words of my Rabbi "as much as the child NEEDS" - it is also healthy for a child to be left alone. Part of the attachment is they feel safe being without the parent.

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy of course

Comment: I don't think there is a prescribed amount as every child is different and has different needs. It is very much a case of chanoch lenaar al pi darko. It is definitely important to spend time with the child in a non-learning capacity. Even R Chaim Kanievsky zt"l relates how his father the Steipler zt"l would make time to walk with him on Shabbos afternoon when it got too dark to learn.

Comment: Jewish life is Torah.

Comment: Raising children isn't like using a recipe book. You have to deal with the child you have. So a special needs kid, for example, would need more time than regular kids.

Comment: a 1 year old ideally would love to be with someone 98% of the time, with normal needs. Traditionally it is the mother, but I also can imagine he is desperate to be with his dad too and I am just wondering if the Torah encourages that and how much.